Does Spring have a class-level @Value?
I have configuration with
my-class
  prop1: val1
  prop2: val2

And the class
MyClass {
  @Value("${my-class.prop1}")
  private String strProp1;

  @Value("${my-class.prop2}")
  private String strProp2;
}

Can I use some class level property so I only need write
// @Value("${my-class}")
MyClass {
  @Value("${prop1}")
  private String strProp1;

  @Value("${prop2}")
  private String strProp2;
}

I would like to still use the @Value annotation just get rid of the property name prefix

see @ConfigurationProperties - https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Thnx @JAsgarov. When I use @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "${my-class}") I get prefix must be in canonical form. when prefix="my-class", I get cannot find decleration on @Value("${prop1}")

Use @ConfigurationProperties and with that you don't need @Value. Just provide the prefix, name your properties the same as in your configuration (so prop1 instead of strProp1) and everything will be done automaticallyl.
